# How do I pass a function as a parameter to a function in C, if the passed function also takes functions as parameters?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing

So this simple case just prints out `3` when passing a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int
case_1_fn_a(int fn_x(int, int)) {
  return fn_x(1, 2);
}

int
main() {
  int x = case_1_fn_a(add);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

But now I would like to *pass a function to a function*. How do I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int
case_2_fn_a(int fn_x(int, int), int fn_y(int, int)) {
  return add(fn_x(add, add), fn_y(add, add));
}

int
case_2_fn_b(int fn_x(int, int)) {
  return fn_x(1, 2);
}

int
main() {
  int x = case_2_fn_a(case_2_fn_b, case_2_fn_b);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

But I get these errors (I get all kinds of different errors if I try adjusting this or that thing, so nothing works):

```
tmp.c:11:19: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int (int, int)' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  return add(fn_x(add, add), fn_y(add, add));
                  ^~~
tmp.c:11:24: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int (int, int)' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  return add(fn_x(add, add), fn_y(add, add));
                       ^~~
tmp.c:11:35: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int (int, int)' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  return add(fn_x(add, add), fn_y(add, add));
                                  ^~~
tmp.c:11:40: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int (int, int)' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  return add(fn_x(add, add), fn_y(add, add));
                                       ^~~
tmp.c:21:23: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (int (*)(int, int))' to parameter of type 'int (*)(int, int)'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  int x = case_2_fn_a(case_2_fn_b, case_2_fn_b);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.c:10:17: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn_x' here
case_2_fn_a(int fn_x(int, int), int fn_y(int, int)) {
                ^
tmp.c:21:36: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (int (*)(int, int))' to parameter of type 'int (*)(int, int)'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  int x = case_2_fn_a(case_2_fn_b, case_2_fn_b);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.c:10:37: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn_y' here
case_2_fn_a(int fn_x(int, int), int fn_y(int, int)) {
                                    ^
6 warnings generated.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Essentially I want to pass a series of functions to function "A", and then have function "A" take those functions (let's call them functions "B", "C", and "D"), and call *them* with a few functions as parameters. Functions "B", "C" and "D" then take their function arguments, and pass simple values to them like integers or chars.

Comment: Two points. (A) Generally you pass pointers-to-function as functions are not first class objects in c. (B) Typedefs are your friends in simplifying the nasty syntax relating to pointers-to-functions.

Comment: If expected result is 6, you may check [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/4KHY4_), life with typedef`s is easier.

Comment: The errors you get are because `fn_x()` takes two `int` parameters, not two function (pointer) parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, when passing functions as parameters, you typically want to use function pointers instead.  So instead of this as a parameter:

```
int fn_x(int, int)
```

You would use this:

```
int (*fn_x)(int, int)
```

Now for the main problem: functions (and function pointers) as parameters and return values can have confusing syntax.  Creating typedefs for function pointers greatly simplifies this.

So let's make the following typedefs:

```
typedef int (*addfunc)(int, int);
typedef int (*fnb)(addfunc);
typedef int (*fna)(fnb, fnb);
```

So now you have:

```
int
case_2_fn_a(fnb fn_x, fnb fn_y) {
  return add(fn_x(add), fn_y(add));
}

int
case_2_fn_b(addfunc fn_x) {
  return fn_x(1, 2);
}
```

As you can see, the syntax is much cleaner.  It's also more apparent that the body of `case_2_fn_a` had a error where `fn_x` and `fn_y` were being passed two parameters instead of one.

If you *really* wanted to do this without typedefs, `case_2_fn_a` would look like this:

```
int
case_2_fn_a(int (*fn_x)(int (*)(int,int)), int (*fn_y)(int (*)(int,int))) {

  return add(fn_x(add), fn_y(add));
}
```

Comment: Using explicit function pointers accomplishes nothing. Parameters with function type are automatically adjusted to be pointers, and function designators used as arguments are automatically converted to pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, use function pointers:

Case 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int
case_1_fn_a(int(*fn_x)()) {
  return (*fn_x)(1, 2);
}

int
main() {
  int x = case_1_fn_a(&add);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Case 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int
case_2_fn_a(int (*fn_x)(), int(*fn_y)()) {
  return add((*fn_x)(&add), (*fn_y)(&add));
}

int
case_2_fn_b(int(*fn_x)()) {
  return (*fn_x)(1, 2);
}

int
main() {
  int x = case_2_fn_a(&case_2_fn_b, &case_2_fn_b);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using explicit function pointers accomplishes nothing. Parameters with function type are automatically adjusted to be pointers, and function designators used as arguments are automatically converted to pointers.